# Convert rows into columns

Tags: python, ruby, perl, unix

I have a file in rows as below and would like to convert into two column format.

```
>00000_x1688514
TGCTTGGACTACATATGGTTGAGGGTTGTA
>00001_x238968
TGCTTGGACTACATATTGTTGAGGGTTGTA
...
```

Desired output is

```
>00000_x1688514 TGCTTGGACTACATATGGTTGAGGGTTGTA
>00001_x238968 TGCTTGGACTACATATTGTTGAGGGTTGTA
...
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: What's the problem? Just read in the file and output 1 line for every two lines.

Comment: Is it me or does the example input == desired output?

Comment: @JonClements -- I think the `>` characters are actually in the file.  They're not actually marking the start of a line.

Comment: @mgilson You're right, the > characters denote the beginning of a header line for a particular entry. To me, it looks like the [FASTA file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format). But what do i know, i'm just a chemist ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if you are aware of the BioPerl modules for reading/writing and other genetic functions. Your problem can be written like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Bio::SeqIO;

my $file = 'o33.txt';
my $in  = Bio::SeqIO->new( -file   =>  $file,
                           -format => 'fasta');

while ( my $seq = $in->next_seq() ) {
    print $seq->id, "\t", $seq->seq, "\n";
}

__END__
00000_x1688514  TGCTTGGACTACATATGGTTGAGGGTTGTA
00001_x238968   TGCTTGGACTACATATTGTTGAGGGTTGTA
```

Answer (score 6):

In python:

```
fd = open('filepath')
cols = izip(fd, fd)
with open('output_filepath') as outfile:
    for col in cols:
        outfile.write('\t'.join(col).replace('\n', '') +'\n')
```

The desired output should be in `output_filepath`

Comment: That is an extremely clever use of `izip` (I would never have thought of "zipping" a generator with itself to break it into chunks.)

Comment: @mgilson: I wish I had come up with it myself. I read it first in another SO post, which I unfortunately am unable to find ATM. But that was exact feeling when I read it too.

Comment: Just a nit-pick: `''.join(col).replace('\n', '\t')` is probably better as: `'\t'.join(col).replace('\n', '')`.  I think it is a little more clear and it doesn't tack an extra tab on the end of the line.

Answer (score 2):

Another Perl option is to set the record delimiter to '>', to read in two lines at a time, then substitute the newline for a tab:

```
use Modern::Perl;

local $/ = '>';
do { s/\n/\t/; print }
  for <DATA>;

__DATA__
>00000_x1688514
TGCTTGGACTACATATGGTTGAGGGTTGTA
>00001_x238968
TGCTTGGACTACATATTGTTGAGGGTTGTA
```

Output:

```
>00000_x1688514 TGCTTGGACTACATATGGTTGAGGGTTGTA
>00001_x238968  TGCTTGGACTACATATTGTTGAGGGTTGTA
```

For a file:

```
use Modern::Perl;
use autodie;

open my $inFile,  '<', 'inFile.txt';
open my $outFile, '>', 'outFile.txt';

local $/ = '>';
do { s/\n/\t/; print $outFile $_ }
  for <$inFile>;

close $inFile;
close $outFile;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

One approach:

```
perl -i -pe 's/\n/ / unless m/^[ACGT]+$/' FILENAME
```

This will in-place edit the file `FILENAME`, replacing a newline with a space in every line that isn't a string of A's, C's, G's, and T's.

Comment: `perl -i -pe ...`.   You used the n switch where you need p instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{ printf "%s", $0 (substr( $0, 1, 1 ) == ">" ? " " : ORS) }' infile
```

Output:

```
>00000_x1688514 TGCTTGGACTACATATGGTTGAGGGTTGTA
>00001_x238968 TGCTTGGACTACATATTGTTGAGGGTTGTA
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby I'd use something like:

```
File.readlines('test.txt').map(&:strip).each_slice(2) do |row|
  puts row.join(' ')
end
```

Which outputs:

```
>00000_x1688514 TGCTTGGACTACATATGGTTGAGGGTTGTA
>00001_x238968 TGCTTGGACTACATATTGTTGAGGGTTGTA
```

Answer (score 0):

A tidier Python solution:

```
from itertools import izip

with open('test.txt') as inf, open('newtest.txt', 'w') as outf:
    for head,body in izip(inf, inf):
        outf.write(head.rstrip() + ' ' + body)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input is in true `FASTA` format, you can use `awk` and the `getline` function:

```
awk '/^>/ { printf "%s ", $0; getline; print }' file.txt
```

Output:

```
>00000_x1688514 TGCTTGGACTACATATGGTTGAGGGTTGTA
>00001_x238968 TGCTTGGACTACATATTGTTGAGGGTTGTA
```

HTH